# Яка етимологія слова "лепський"?

Tags: етимологія

Сьогодні натрапила на таке слово, як *лепський*.

[Словник української мови](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=47309&page=1493) подає, що:

**ЛЕ́ПСЬКИЙ**, а, е, розм. Хороший, гарний.

Тож яка етимологія слова *лепський*?

Моя гіпотеза така: ймовірно походить від слова [*лепта*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=47311&page=1493) — несок у яку-небудь суспільну справу. У такому випадку могло відбутись спрощення: *лептський → лепський*. Але тоді не сходиться саме значення, яке є доволі різним.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Етимолоґічниь словник української мови](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) 3, сторінка 224:

> **ле́пський** «хороший, гарний; [розумний Исслед. п. яз.]»;
>
> запозичення з польської мови; п. [łebski] «розумний; чималий; хвацький; гарний, лепський». łepski «тс.» є похідим від łeb «голова», якому відповідає українське *лоб*; значення «гарний» розвинулося в польській мові внаслідок злиження з lepszy «кращий, ліпший».
>
> Критенко Мовозн. 1969/1, 61; Онышкевич Исслед. п. яз. 244; Richhardt 73; Sławski 5 94; Brückner 309.
>
> Див. ще **лоб**.
>
> ---
>
> **ле́пта** «дрібна мідна монета у стародавній Греції; пожертвування або милостиня; вклад у яку-небудь суспільну справу»;
>
> російське, білоруське *ле́пта* «тс.», др. *лепта* «грецька дрібна монета», *лепѣта*, польське lepton «тс.», болгарське *ле́пта* «пожертвування», схв. lȅpta «грецька дрібна монета», стсл. **лєп(ъ)та** «тс.»
>
> через церковнословʼянську мову запозичено в давньоруську з грецької; гр. λεπτόν (мн. λεπτά) «дрібна мідна монета»утворене від λεπτός «тонкий, дрібнии», повʼазаного з дієсловом λέπω «знімаю оболонку, обдираю».
>
> СІС 390; Фасмер 2 484; Преобр. 1 448; Горяев 185; Kopaliński 567; БЕР 3 365; Bern. 1 702; Mikl. EW 165; Meillet Études 187; Frisk 2 105—107.
>
> Див. ще **ле́пра**. Пор. **ла́пик**, **ла́поть**, **лепі́стка**.